# loop over list of strings and delete record

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have json file contain:

```
<Attendance>: 191 : 2021-05-04 12:26:35 (2, 0)

<Attendance>: 166 : 2021-05-04 14:13:50 (1, 0)
```

i need return only row with (1, 0) first number equal 1

Ex:

```
<Attendance>: 166 : 2021-05-04 14:13:50 (1, 0)
```

Any kind of help please?

Comment: How does your code fail? Why are you looping to range(300)? Why are you writing the entire data object, and why write it every time you hit an entry with status 2?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```
some_list = [
    {"uid": 3, "user_id": "2", "timestamp": 1619611345.0, "status": 1, "punch": 0},
    {"uid": 167, "user_id": "166", "timestamp": 1619612463.0, "status": 2, "punch": 0},
    {"uid": 188, "user_id": "199", "timestamp": 1619613498.0, "status": 1, "punch": 0}
    ]

for i in some_list:
    if(i['status']==2):
        print(i)
```

returns:

```
{'uid': 167, 'user_id': '166', 'timestamp': 1619612463.0, 'status': 2, 'punch': 0}
```

Please vote up if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you for reply it work perfectly.
Sorry i cant vote because i am a new user.

Comment: Please can you help me i have this 
<Attendance>: 191 : 2021-05-04 12:26:35 (2, 0)
<Attendance>: 166 : 2021-05-04 14:13:50 (1, 0)
i need return only row with (1, 0) first number equal 1
Ex:
<Attendance>: 166 : 2021-05-04 14:13:50 (1, 0)

Comment: that is okay,  you should be able to accept the answer as the acepted answer since it works (and in clean & concise).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get your expected output with the following:

```
with open(f) as infile:
    json_obj = json.load(infile)

for d in json_obj:
    if d['status'] == 2:
        file1 = 'D:/abd/biometric-attendance-sync-tool-master/logs/floor_7_192_168_1_2_last_fetch_dump - t.json'
        with open(file1, 'w') as outfile:
            outfile.write(json.dumps(d))
```

As for your edit which says you're working with a list of strings, you can get a list of the strings that end with `(1, 0)` by filtering them out with a list comprehension:

whatever your infile `f` is called (some `.json`):

```
[
    "<Attendance>: 191 : 2021-05-04 12:26:35 (2, 0)",
    "<Attendance>: 166 : 2021-05-04 14:13:50 (1, 0)"
]
```

and the .py you're working with:

```
with open(f) as infile:
    json_obj = json.load(infile)

res = [s for s in json_obj if s.endswith('(1, 0)')]

file1 = 'D:/abd/biometric-attendance-sync-tool-master/logs/floor_7_192_168_1_2_last_fetch_dump - t.json'
with open(file1, "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write(s for s in res)
```

Comment: Please can you help me i have this 
<Attendance>: 191 : 2021-05-04 12:26:35 (2, 0)
<Attendance>: 166 : 2021-05-04 14:13:50 (1, 0)
i need return only row with (1, 0) first number equal 1
Ex:
<Attendance>: 166 : 2021-05-04 14:13:50 (1, 0)

Comment: @SamerAdnan please update your question with your follow-up case formatted properly

Comment: @SamerAdnan I'm confused, your new data is not json

Comment: it just a list of strings

Comment: only list of strings

Comment: I think we need to use regex. I use this  \[*(?:\+(\d-\d))?(\d+)\s* but it matches all digits in string i just need to match digits with () and when match it compare the first number if is equal to 2 delete all line

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code to this, this should work for you.

```
#assuming your data in the variable data with this format
data = [
    {"uid": 3, "user_id": "2", "timestamp": 1619611345.0, "status": 1, "punch": 0},
    {"uid": 167, "user_id": "166", "timestamp": 1619612463.0, "status": 2, "punch": 0},
    {"uid": 188, "user_id": "199", "timestamp": 1619613498.0, "status": 1, "punch": 0}
    ]

#inside json.load you will write the following code

filteredData = list(filter(lambda x: x['status'] == 2, data))

json_object = json.dumps(filteredData)

file1 = open('D:/abd/biometric-attendance-sync-tool-master/logs/floor_7_192_168_1_2_last_fetch_dump - t.json', 'w')

# Writing a string to file
file1.write(json_object)

# Closing file
file1.close()
```

The output will be a file with the JSON object

```
[{"uid": 167, "user_id": "166", "timestamp": 1619612463.0, "status": 2, "punch": 0}]
```

Comment: Thank you for reply.
Please can you help me i have this
<Attendance>: 191 : 2021-05-04 12:26:35 (2, 0)

<Attendance>: 166 : 2021-05-04 14:13:50 (1, 0)
i need return only row with (1, 0) first number equal 1
Ex:
<Attendance>: 166 : 2021-05-04 14:13:50 (1, 0)